# cancel editing when clicking outside gridview c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to run the OnRowCancelingEdit when I click outside the gridview. How can I do that in asp c#?

```
protected void gridlist_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
{
    gridlist.EditIndex = -1;
    SortGridView(sortExpression, sortDirection);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a couple of lines of jQuery. The first part binds the click to the entire document, finds the editindex and does a PostBack as you would by clicking the Cancel link inside the GridView. The second part is to make sure the editing does does cancel itself by clicking in the same GridView.

```
<script>
    $('body').click(function (e) {
        var editIndex = <%= GridView1.EditIndex %>;
        if (editIndex >= 0)
            __doPostBack('<%= GridView1.UniqueID %>','Cancel$<%= GridView1.EditIndex %>')
    });

    $('#<%= GridView1.ClientID %>').click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This line isnt working  var editIndex = <%= gridlistOGTSUProjects.EditIndex %>; It has some squiggly lines under the < and >

Comment: The script must be placed on the aspx page itself. Not in an external js file. Then it will work. Tested the snippet myself ofcourse ;)

Answer (score -1):

You may need to try the Leave or LostFocus event.

Here's info on the LostFocus event.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.lostfocus?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8

I haven't run into your issue specifically, but I would think that once you hit the LostFocus event, you should be able to cancel the edit there.